How to implement email verification for registration in asp.net mvc, something like gmail codes
I want like after the initial registration such is inputting username, email, password, other personal infos, the user is not yet registered as he will recieve a code from the email, how to do that in asp.net mvc

you can do this in any language  procedure is same  you have to use activation code send to user save in database and email it to user . once he enter that on activation page     match it with save data in table and mark user activated in database. if you are asking how to write a code  then  refer  [tour] ask  [ask]

One solution :
add a column to your user table as isVerified. You can set this as 0 initially
and you will need another column in the same table or another table to store the OTP/Verification code. Better to store with a date time because you will need to set expiry date along with the OTP.
when the user submit the sign up details, set isVerified = 0 and generate random OTP and store it.
Using SmtpClient you can implement the email sending logics. You can easily google that and get an idea and Ask question here if you had a blocker in your code.
